# Subtracting dates give me error in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, datetime

I use age to get the interval between to date fields. Their type is timestamp.

My code is as below:

```
select age(timestamp MySecondDateField, timestamp MyFirstDateField)
```

The data in my field contains:

```
2014-01-26 09:53:17.036359
```

How should I subtract two dates?

When I use age as below it works:

```
select age(timestamp '2001-04-10', timestamp '1957-06-13')
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If those columns are `timestamp` (or `date`) columns, just use

```
age(MySecondDateField, MyFirstDateField)
```

The `timestamp` or `date` prefix is only needed for date/timestamp *constants*.

If those columns are varchar then you should change them to a proper timestamp/date datatype.

Until you do that, you can use the `to_date()` or `to_timestamp()` function to convert a string to a date, e.g:

```
to_timestamp(MySecondDateField, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
```

For more details on those functions, please see the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html

You should never store dates (or numbers) as varchar/text columns. To fix your table, you can use a conversion function when you run the alter table:

```
alter table wrong_design 
   alter MyFirstDateField type timestamp 
   using to_timestamp(some_col, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.us')
```